# Change local network name via Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a beginner in Node.js and would like to know if it is possible to develop an application that renames the local network if the user allows it. If it is not possible with Node, is there any programming language that will allow this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you're after is changing window's network adapter name.
running `netsh interface` in **cmd.exe** should do the trick:

```
netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" newname="My Network"
```

[image: netsh interface set interface name]